# Does Z3 have troubles with division?

Tags: z3, division, smt, z3py

During a project, I encountered a phenomenon I can't explain. It is boiled down in the following minimal example (using Z3Py) which should be unsat but returns a model.

```py
from z3 import *

solver = Solver()

x = Int("x")

# The next proposition is clearly unsatisfiable
solver.add(And(x > 0, (x + 1) * (1 / (x + 1)) != 1))
solver.add(x == 1)

# Still, Z3 provides a "model"
print(solver.check())
print(solver.model())
```

Is there anything I am missing? Is it forbidden to use division in certain situations?

Z3 version: 4.8.14
Python version: 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you use `/` over integers, than the result is an integer itself. That is, we use integer division; which in SMTLib is defined to be the Euclidian one. See https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-Ints.shtml for details.

This means that the expression `1 / (1+1)` reduces to `0`, since division produces an integer. So you end up with `0 != 1`, which is true, and thus your problem is satisfiable.

If you want division to produce reals, then you should either start with a real `x` (i.e., `x = Real("x")`) in which case your problem will be `unsat`; or convert the arguments to be over the reals, via an expression of the form `ToReal(x)`; which again will produce `unsat` for your problem.

So, in the first case, your modification will be:

```py
x = Real('x')
```

casting the problem over reals. Or, if you want to keep `x` an integer, yet the division to be over the reals, you should use:

```py
solver.add(And(x > 0, ToReal(x + 1) * (1 / ToReal(x + 1)) != 1))
```

which does the conversion.

I should note that mixing integers and reals in this way can lead to hard problems in general, and the solver might end up reporting `unknown`. But that's besides the point for your particular question here.